# Always generate thumbnail after sideloading image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm sideloading an image into wordpress from youtube. it works fine and the key part of the code is:

```
// sideload it into wordpress (generates various sizes)
$thumbid = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post->ID );
if ( is_wp_error($thumbid) ) { // deal with error here }

// kill existing attachment first, if any
wp_delete_attachment(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), true);

// and finally associate post with new thumbnail
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbid );
```

Here's the problem. I have registered 5 image sizes with `add_image_size` in my Wordpress functions file. When I sideload per the code above, WP generates all the thumbs for the image in all the sizes *except one,* 640x400. I believe it's skipping this thumb since 640x400 is actually larger than the image that is returned from YouTube. However, I need to get that thumbnail no matter what-- I want to force Wordpress to generate that thumbnail. How can I do that?

I register the image size just like all others:

```
 add_image_size( 'static-head', 640, 400, true );
```

So I'm looking for function sort of like `wp_generate_thumbnail($thumbid, 'static-head')`, that will leave the right 640x400 image in the uploads folder.

Thank you--

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use wp_generate_attachment_metadata and wp_update_attachment_metadata to do this.

```
// sideload it into wordpress (generates various sizes)
$thumbid = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post->ID );
if ( is_wp_error($thumbid) ) { // deal with error here }

// If this function is undefined in the environment where it is to be used,
// such as within a Shortcode, use the include function:
include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// create the thumbnails
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $thumbid, $file_array['tmp_name'] );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $thumbid,  $attach_data );

// kill existing attachment first, if any
wp_delete_attachment(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), true);

// and finally associate post with new thumbnail
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbid );
```

wp_generate_attachment_metadata creates the thumbnails.  wp_update_attachment_metadata makes sure they are actually part of the media object

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem? Show a sample code snippet.

Comment: Not cool to vote my response down when it is the correct answer to your question. Look at the WordPress codex:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata